# Insert queryset results into ManytoManyfield

Tags: django

I have a models.py file that looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from common.models import Record
from tinymce import models as tinymce_models

# Create your models here.
class Address(Record):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.ip)

    ip = models.IPAddressField(unique=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Addresses"

class Servers(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.server_name)

    server_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ip_address = models.ForeignKey(Address)
    secondary_ips = models.ManyToManyField(Address, verbose_name = 'Secondary IPs', blank=True, related_name='secondary_ips')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Servers"
```

I have a list of IP's and Servers in the system.  I am trying to have the ManytoManyField only display the list of IP's that are not currently associated with a server.

I have the following queryset:

```
inner_qs = Servers.objects.values_list('ip_address_id', flat=True)
entries = Address.objects.exclude(id__in=inner_qs)
```

It returns only the IP addresses that are not in the Server table.  I do not know how to incorporate those results into my ManytoManyField and where I am supposed to place my queryset.  I currently only get the results when I enter the django Shell

Any ideas,

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do with the ips that aren't attached to servers?

Comment: I'm trying to have those IP's show up in my filter_horizontal = ('secondary_ips',) in my admin.py file.  Those should be the only IP's I can choose from.  Instead, it lists all of the IP addresses in my Address table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this answer here: [Filter ManyToMany box in Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226760/filter-manytomany-box-in-django-admin)

In short, you need to create a custom form that extends `django.forms.ModelForm`. There, in `__init__`-method, place new options to the right widget (`secondary_ips`). Finally, add `form = YourOwnForm` to the `ServerAdmin` class you are using.

I suggest modifying `related_names` in the `Servers`-model:

```
class Servers(models.Model):
    # ...
    ip_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='server')
    secondary_ips = models.ManyToManyField(Address, verbose_name = 'Secondary IPs', \
        blank=True, related_name='servers_secondary')
```

Then, you can use a nice QuerySet:

```
allowed_addresses = Address.objects.filter(server=None)
```

**Secondary addresses**

Of course, this filters only the IPs that are as a primary IP in some server. If you want to filter out also the ips that are as a secondary_ip in some other server, things get a bit trickier:

You need to filter also on `servers_secondary=None`. But you can't filter out the IPs selected for the current object (the server that is edited in the admin), or those selected IPs will disappear too.

Accomplish this using [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), and grab the currently selected object from `kwargs`. Your custom Form's `__init__`-method will then look something like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourOwnForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = kwargs.get('instance')
    allowed_addresses = Address.objects \
        .filter(server=None) \
        .filter(Q(servers_secondary=None) | Q(servers_secondary=instance))
    choices = []
    for choice in allowed_addresses:
        choices.append((choice.id, choice.ip))
    w = self.fields['secondary_ips'].widget
    w.choices = choices
```

**Primary address dropdown menu**

Folowing the same method, it is also possible to filter items in the primary IP address drop-down menu. Of course, care must be taken not to remove the selected IP address from the list.

Comment: Thanks Mikko.  I'll try that out and let know know what happens.

Comment: Hi Mikko, It works if I already have Servers listed in the database by loading them in through fixtures.  But if I start from a clean database, I can add IP's just fine, but when I try to add a Server I get the following error:  Exception Type:  KeyError
Exception Value:  

'instance'

Comment: Hi again,  I was able to fix it by adding a try/except.  try:
            instance = kwargs['instance']
        except:
            instance = None   Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There should be some protection in case `kwargs['instance']` is `None`. Try/except is a good solution, other one is `kwargs.get('instance')`. I edited my answer to use `get()`.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to add a queryset to a many to many field first change it into a list and add it as positional arguments using *

Example

```
# Returns a queryset
permissions = Permission.objects.all()

# Add the results to the many to many field (notice the *)

group = MyGroup.objects.get(name='test')

group.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

Comment: Two queries instead of one :(

Comment: @DylanYoung if you have a way to do it with one query please do share

Comment: Actually I was mistaken; it's three queries.  Something like this does it in two, assuming you know the group pk: ThroughModel = MyGroup.permissions.through; ThroughModel.objects.bulk_create(ThroughModel(permission=permission_id, mygroup=group_pk) for permission_id in Permission.objects.all())

Comment: Bit of a cumbersome pattern. My comment was more on the Django ORM than your answer :) Still struggling with a one query solution.

Answer (score 2):

Returns a queryset

```
permissions = Permission.objects.all()
```

Add the results to the many to many field (notice the `*`)

```
group = MyGroup.objects.get(name='test')
group.permissions.add(*permissions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here because I had a model with a manytomanyfield pointing to this model "CampaignsProducts" which its **str** property was generating many queries :

Before :

```
class CampaignsProducts(mdlcom.CommonStructure):
 product = models.ForeignKey(
    'products.Product',
    verbose_name=u'Producto',
    null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_product_set",
 )
 campaign = models.ForeignKey(
    'prices.Campaigns',
    verbose_name=u'Campaña',
    null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_campaign_set",
 )
 def __str__(self):
    return '{} - {}'.format(self.product.name, self.campaign.name)
```

In order to fix it, I changed the following "**str**" property

```
def __str__(self):
   return str(self.id)
```

and the solution that was provided by Mikko, saved my life :

```
class CouponForm(forms.ModelForm):
NO_REQUIRED = [
    'sellers', 'platforms', 'campaigns_product',
]

class Meta:
    model = mdlpri.Coupon
    fields = '__all__'

def get_campaigns_choices(self):
    qscampaigns = (
        mdlpri.CampaignsProducts.objects.all()
        .select_related("product")
        .select_related("campaign")
        .order_by("id")
    )
    choices = []
    for item in qscampaigns:
        wdescription = '{} - {}'.format(
            item.product.name, item.campaign.name
        )
        choices.append((item.id, wdescription))

    return choices

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CouponForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for wfield in self.NO_REQUIRED:
        self.fields[wfield].required = False
```

> ## personalize choices
>
> ```
>     w = self.fields["campaigns_product"].widget
>     w.choices = self.get_campaigns_choices()
> ```

Query Before the change (by product):

```
SELECT "products_product"."id", "products_product"."name", "products_product"."custom", "products_product"."created_at", "products_product"."updated_at", "products_product"."active", "products_product"."position", "products_product"."url", "products_product"."for_bonus_platform", "products_product"."for_cms_platform", "products_product"."for_store_platform", "products_product"."for_call_center_platform", "products_product"."for_ibk_platform", "products_product"."for_scotiabank_platform", "products_product"."for_bbva_platform", "products_product"."for_refurbished_platform" FROM "products_product" WHERE "products_product"."id" = 1
```

Query after the change :

```
SELECT "prices_campaignsproducts"."id", "prices_campaignsproducts"."date_created_at", "prices_campaignsproducts"."created_at", "prices_campaignsproducts"."updated_at", "prices_campaignsproducts"."user_id", "prices_campaignsproducts"."last_user_modified_id", "prices_campaignsproducts"."product_id", "prices_campaignsproducts"."campaign_id", "prices_campaignsproducts"."price", "prices_campaignsproducts"."is_active", "prices_campaignsproducts"."expiration_from", "prices_campaignsproducts"."expiration_to", "products_product"."id", "products_product"."name", "products_product"."custom", "products_product"."created_at", "products_product"."updated_at", "products_product"."active", "products_product"."position", "products_product"."url", "products_product"."for_bonus_platform", "products_product"."for_cms_platform", "products_product"."for_store_platform", "products_product"."for_call_center_platform", "products_product"."for_ibk_platform", "products_product"."for_scotiabank_platform", "products_product"."for_bbva_platform", "products_product"."for_refurbished_platform", "prices_campaigns"."id", "prices_campaigns"."date_created_at", "prices_campaigns"."created_at", "prices_campaigns"."updated_at", "prices_campaigns"."user_id", "prices_campaigns"."last_user_modified_id", "prices_campaigns"."name", "prices_campaigns"."is_active" FROM "prices_campaignsproducts" INNER JOIN "products_product" ON ("prices_campaignsproducts"."product_id" = "products_product"."id") INNER JOIN "prices_campaigns" ON ("prices_campaignsproducts"."campaign_id" = "prices_campaigns"."id") ORDER BY "prices_campaignsproducts"."id" ASC
```

Just wanted to share my experience.

Best regards,