# limiting the queryset for ManyToMany MultipleSelect in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_dates = ManyToManyField("EventDate")
    #...

class EventDate(models.Model):
    event_date = DateField()
    #...
```

However, in the django admin `MultipleSelect` form field that gets show for event_dates in the `EventAdmin`, I'd like to limit the queryset to event_dates that are not in the past.

The queryset would be something like:

```
event_date_queryset = EventDate.objects.filter(event_date__gte = datetime.date.today())
```

But where can I set this queryset so that only non-past dates show up in the field?

(I don't currently have a custom form for the `EventAdmin` but would be happy to add one.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter ManyToMany box in Django Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226760/filter-manytomany-box-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try:

```
event_dates = models.ManyToManyField("EventDate", limit_choices_to={'event_date__gte': date.today()})
```

taken from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to

but then only dates in the future are shown, even if some dates in the past are still associated to `Event`.

If you also want all the dates you previously associated to `Event` you could manipulate `ModelForm` as following

```
from datetime import date

from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Q

from models import Event, EventDate

class EventAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'event_dates' in self.initial:
            self.fields['event_dates'].queryset = EventDate.objects.filter(Q(pk__in=self.initial['event_dates']) | Q(event_date__gte=date.today()))
        else:
            self.fields['event_dates'].queryset = EventDate.objects.filter(event_date__gte=date.today())

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventAdminForm
    filter_horizontal = ['event_dates']
```

Comment: yes, i meant event_dates and updated the question to accurately reflect that.  Good point on wanting to keep event_dates that are in the past but already selected. The more complete solution is probably the one I'm after, although I learned something new with limit_choices_to.  Thanks!

Comment: I ended up using the second (more comprehensive) approach almost verbatim, works great.

Comment: this is awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is to do it in the admin

Your models

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_dates = ManyToManyField("EventDate")
    #...

class EventDate(models.Model):
    event_date = DateField()
    #...
```

Now in your admin file

This has the added advantage that it only returns event dates only for the current event that you are looking at using the reverse lookup `event__id=event_id`

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_field_queryset(self, db, db_field, request):
        """
        If the ModelAdmin specifies ordering, the queryset should respect that
        ordering.  Otherwise don't specify the queryset, let the field decide
        (returns None in that case).
        """
        if db_field.name == 'event_dates':
            event_id = int(request.resolver_match.args[0])

            return db_field.remote_field.model._default_manager.filter(
                              event__id=event_id,
                              event_date__gte = datetime.date.today()
            )

        super().get_field_queryset(db, db_field, request)
```

Comment: For Django 2 app I just needed to change id get to
request.resolver_match.kwargs['object_id']